# Adding floating text next to centered images

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to add some texts next to centered images. I want to keep images in the center of my page and texts just floating on sides of pictures (without moving images to the sides of the page)

[my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlrTQ.png)

This is my code (with a random free image for question purposes only):

```css
    .whole h2 {
        margin-top: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .row1 {
        height: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .img1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
        display:block;
    }
    
    .text1 {
        text-align: right;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .img2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .row2 {
        height: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .text2 {
        text-align: left;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>page</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="whole">
                <h2>Experience</h2>
                <div class="row1">
                    <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img1" alt="img1">
                    <div class="text1">
                        <h3>year</h3>
                        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row2">
                    <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img2" alt="img1">
                    <div class="text2">
                        <h3>year</h3>
                        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried using inline-block for images, but then I couldn't center them. In general, the texts somehow push the images away from the center and I cannot find a similar case as mine online. Thank you in advance for any hints.

Comment: What about a grid layout? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is the best solution as I want to keep the text close to the images.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way with your code is to use position absolute

```css
.whole h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row1 {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.img1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.text1 {
  text-align: right;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:15%;
 
}

.img2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.row2 {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: left;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  right:15%;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="whole">
    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <div class="row1"  >
      <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img1" alt="img1">
      <div class="text1">
        <h3>year</h3>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img2" alt="img1">
      <div class="text2">
        <h3>year</h3>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

or we could do this with flex:  when you use absolute it takes the element out of the regular dom flow.  Better yo use flex, makes responsive designs easier

```css
.whole h2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row1 {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.img1 {
  margin: 0 auto;  
  display: block;
}

.text1{
   text-align:right;}

.r1{
   width:30%;}

.img2 {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: block;
}

.row2 {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: left;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="whole">
    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <div class="row1">
       <div class="text1 r1">
        <h3>year</h3>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img1 r1" alt="img1">
      
      <div class='r1'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
      <div class='r1'>&nbsp;</div>
      <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/285/open-book_1f4d6.png" class="img2 r1" alt="img1">
      <div class="text2 r1">
        <h3>year</h3>
        <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```